# Pinterest share image is undefined/empty

Tags: html, wordpress, pinterest

I am using a Wordpress theme called Salient. Everything works great so far.
Except for the Pinterest Share button.

For some reason the Pinterest popup shows an undefined image.
Is there somehow I can change the img source?

Here is the website: http://startscaling.com/story-scaling-logo/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably theme is looking to a featured image to post to Pinterest.. try adding a featured image or some images into post content ..